# Remove NSNotification Observer from UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsnotification

I have `UIVIewController` and In that I have placed `UITableView`
`UITableView` Contain cell where cell contains `UICollectionView`
Each cell has its own collectionView.
Now, I want to update some rows of collection view of different sections based on tableview header.
My tableview contains section Header and button inside

Eg : When I click on TableView header I want to update some of row of its cell's collectionView so here I have using the `NSNotification` for callToUpdate rows in collectionView (All collectionView Related stuff is placed on cell.m file of `UITableView`)

But the issue is that as cell scroll , the observer is keep adding and my post notification method called multiple time.

I also wrote code for remove observer but it did not work.

Comment: could you edit your question to show the code of *how* & *where* the observer is being added to the table view cell?

Comment: @user816 : This is regarding the edit - Statements like Hi, thanks should be avoided. And since OP has mentioned NSNotification, Swift isn't appropriate tag here.

Comment: Instead of `NotificationCenter` you can use `Delegate` to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

`NotificationCenter` will behave like this only, for example if you are using `NotificationCenter.default.addObserver` in `viewWillAppear` you have to remove the observer by using `NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver` in `viewWillDisAppear`. This is the usage description by Apple for `NotificationCenter`.

As `cellForRowAtIndexPath` will be called for multiple times, the `observer` also added for multiple times. Better advice is to use `Delegate`. when tapping on header you have to call the delegate method to do the desired action.